# Bootstrap navbar adjustment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to align my navbar placed at the top of my webpage, but somehow one of items appears straight down "Kontakt".

I would like all items i have to be in same line. Second issue is i cannot make my logo when click on it redirect to my page at the top again.

[image: Screenshoot]

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="img/ico2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Witamy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i> Usługi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Realizacje</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cooperation" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Etapy </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-stack-exchange"></i> O nas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="social-media hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.mywebpage.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the wrapping `div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`s for a `navbar` to work.
And wrap a link tag around the image to redirect it to your homepage.

**Update**:
Issue 1) There are limitations to how many items Bootstrap can show in a navigation bar. Please check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar) and read the limitations.
Issue 2) I have fixed the code. Please ensure that jQuery and bootstrap JS files are loaded.
Issue 3) I cannot recreate the issue. It seems related to the logo size. Can you post a jsFiddle?

**Updated** Here is the fixed code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="//www.your-any-webste.com/"><img src="img/ico2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Witamy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i> Usługi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Realizacje</a></li>
      <li><a href="#cooperation" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Etapy </a></li>
      <li><a href="#team" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-stack-exchange"></i> O nas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Three issues, it works now however when i add again one more item, then all items are going down so it's like logo stays on position and all items are down (below logo from his right corner). Second issue when webpage is resized to minimum and once i see those items were put into shortcut bar then when i click on it it is not showing any items like it were not working. Third issue when scrool from top a but lower logo image resizing to very slow size and when i back to the top it appears again normal (more than that logo seem to be overcomming border..)